# FB Like button for jQuery Slideshow

Tags: jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I am trying to add a Facebook like button to individual pictures that appear in my jQuery slideshow. I am using the jQuery code from http://www.nitinh.com/static/SlideShow/jQuery.html. Adding the button should not be a problem but getting it to like individual pictures, that appears in the viewer, has me puzzled. I don't want just a whole page like but individual picture like button.

Comment: Just create a page for every picture, and point the link button to the URL of the page

Comment: ... another solution would be to create a generic page that outputs correctly formatted og meta tags when the user agent if the Facebook crawler, but redirect to the actual image if a user tries to visit it

Answer (score 0):

Scibuff posted these comments, which I believe are worthy as answers:

> Just create a page for every picture, and point the link button to the
>   URL of the page.
>
> Another solution would be to create a generic page that outputs
>   correctly formatted og meta tags when the user agent if the Facebook
>   crawler, but redirect to the actual image if a user tries to visit it.